# Should users refrain from making minor edits to a question?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators, grammar

I feel users that can edit posts should refrain from editing other users' posts when they are only making minor grammar and capital case edits.

I don't think their edits add enough value to warrant editing the posts, and the original posters may find it irritating.

I have nothing against edits that add significant value (such as changing an external site link to a screenshot).

Comment: Welcome to Meta, mataal.  Since this question has a downvote, you might want to see ["How does Meta work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-work)

Comment: I just looked at your questions on Stack Overflow, and **none** of them have been edited.  I found only one question on Super User that has *ever* been edited. So what do you mean by 'users' and 'questions'?

Comment: @george- yes never had that problem on stackoverflow. 'questions' was the generalization. fixing.

Comment: I'm not talking about just questions, I've looked at all your posts, and only **one** has been edited. Besides this one. Which is a little ironic.

Comment: @George - Priceless :)

Answer (score 52):

I, as a non-native English speaker, prefer it the other way: please edit user's posts, including mine, *especially* for grammar errors!

Answer (score 47):

Not adding significant value is one thing... but unless it actually *reduces* the value, why would you care? For example, if I were to go through this question and introduce appropriate capitalisation to make it easier for others to read, why should you object to that?

*You* may not care about capitalisation and grammar, but others do. The easier your text is to read, the more effective it will be. Why do you think it's *worse* for your post to be correctly capitalised than not? If an editor is making your post even *slightly* better, what's the problem?

Comment: I'm tempted to replace the 's' with 'z' in capitalisation.

Comment: #1 it's not that i care about capitalization, just that i like writing with none
#2 the edits that i am referring make grammar edits that are so minor that it's questionable- like i already said "how do i" was changed to "how can i "?
#3 these minor edits take away my attention form the action question content to wasting time with such a thread on meta. :)

Comment: Because sometimes those are, true, minor edits. Sometimes, on the other hand, somebody takes and rephrases the whole question in a way that I would never had asked it myself. The question still stays the same but I appreciated the old way/style it was put as well. Not everyone speaks the same (form of) english.

Comment: @mataal: The point of text on a site like this is to communicate. Why do you *want* to make it harder to communicate than it has to be? You may like writing with no capitalisation, but I think it's pretty clear that people prefer *reading* with capitalisation. If you don't care about making life easier for those trying to help you, why do you think anyone will bother helping you in the first place?

Comment: @mataal While e.e.cummings could get away with lowercase, he knew what he was doing and why. You are not e.e.cummings. To quote from a great article, "There's a world of difference between great poetry and lazy typing." (see http://everything2.com/title/Capitalize%252C+please for the whole writeup)

Answer (score 28):

Your posts aren't necessarily being edited by moderators.  Anyone with at least 2000 reputation can edit posts (**EDIT** : this has been relaxed; now *anyone* can submit suggested edits for review by 2000-rep users); it's in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Also in the FAQ:

> ### Other people can edit my stuff?!
>
> Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your posts being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

As for my personal opinion — at least until you link to some example questions — I support the editors.  What seems like a minor edit to you may be a very helpful clarification to someone else.  It also makes the site more professional, which is important for the site goals.  All of this goes double if the edits do not change your meaning or detract from your post in any way.

Comment: @popular demand- example would be someone editing this question to correct the sentence casing and change something like "how do i..." to "how can i..."

Comment: @mataai Perhaps if you learned the simple art of the shift key, people would not edit your posts. People who post all in lowercase are frequently seen as either stupid, lazy or both - those doing the edits are probably doing you a big favour in terms of how your question/answer will be perceived by the SO community as a whole.

Comment: @neil hmmm, i hadn't thought of it that way. i prefer typing in lowercase in most of my internet posts since i saw that was jerry yang's style and adopted it. :)

Comment: @Neil - Although I agree on the matter of proper capitalization, that first notion notion is, I must say, one of the most stupid ones I've heard today. Does that mean that people who write in all caps are considered smart, eager or both ?

Comment: @mataal: i often use an all-lower-case typing style for informal situations.  on these sites, that means comments.  for answers and questions, i use a more formal capitalization style and grammar -- as Popular Demand says, again, it makes a more professional post.

Comment: @LDIGAS: YES!!!!  er, no.  wait, what?

Comment: @ldigas Have you heard of this thing called "logic"? If so, please consider applying it to your comments here. How does me suggesting that all lowercase is perceived as bad imply that all uppercase is good?

Comment: @Neil - logic ? Why, yes, I've heard of it. I also found it rather sparse if not entirely absent in your first comment. How else was I supposed to understand it ?

Comment: @quack quixote - (but also to all others to whom it may apply) - my name begins with an L (@Neil - you somehow got it right. Thank you for that!).

Comment: @ldigas I really don't think the comment needed explaining, but since you asked: English has a defined correct capitalization. this is wrong. SO IS THIS. This is correct. Just as people correct spelling and grammatical mistakes, they're free (and in my opinion, welcome) to correct capitalization

Comment: @Michael - A-ah, but it did. For I did not mind the saying that it was incorrect, for it certanly is. What I did mind was Neil's statement that people who do not use proper capitalization are either stupid, lazy or both. Which I simply do not agree with. If a primary function of a language is to transpose meaning with as little as effort on one's behalf as possible, then surely lack of capitalization when the meaning is still properly conveyed, as it is in most cases, is better surely. Not correct, true, but better! "Correct" is simply a matter of an agreement.

Comment: The fact that Neil (or anyone else, for that matter) understood the meaning, is obvious. So the poster's task was successful. If he understood the meaning, he could've helped whether he wished to, or not. But no ! Although the meaning was clear, he choose to fuss over the capitalization, optionally rectifying it (also proving by that, that he understood the meaning, otherwise he would've undoubtedly be unable to do so). And blaming the original poster for that. Which in terms of the problem, to an independent observer, looks like a typical case of creating a problem

Comment: yourself and blaming the other for it. If he didn't on the other hand understand the meaning, he should've stated so (and left). Or voted for closure, or for deletion, or something ...

Comment: But now that I've allowed myself ( sigh :( ) again to be drawn into one of these futile discussions, let me post an additional question. I'm interested in it purely out of curiosity. Why is it that of all the people in the world, users on computer forums (of all kinds), are so sensitive to language rigidness (almost obsessive compulsive like) ? For, some of the linguists I know, are more tolerant to it (they will, mind you, recognize an error - they just will not fuss over it). [btw - going to sleep now ... will respond tomorrow]

Comment: @ldigas "Why is it that of all the people in the world, users on computer forums (of all kinds), are so sensitive to language rigidness (almost obsessive compulsive like)?" If this isn't blindingly obvious to you, I doubt you are actually  a computer programmer.

Comment: @ldigas: ah! sorry 'bout that.  lowercase L and uppercase I look identical in this font.

Comment: @ldigas: Regarding "The fact that Neil (or anyone else, for that matter) understood the meaning, is obvious. So the poster's task was successful." Understanding isn't a black or white matter. There's *ease* of understanding. I could have made a spelling mistake in every word in this comment, and you could probably still have understood it... but it would have been more effort. As a matter of courtesy to readers, I view it as a writer's duty to make text as easy to understand as possible.

Comment: @mataal Snice the hmanun biran can inrpetret wrods wtih ltetrs in wrong order, you even might call the correct letter-order obsolete. But it's obviously nasty to read, so usually one does write correctly. But hey,if you really want to miss out great answers on your questions just because someone as smart as Jon Skeet doesn't want to waste time on reading lowercase only, that's up to you

Comment: @Neil - But, Neil ... have you forgotten that not all languages are case sensitive; the two I use are certanly not and blanks are mostly irrelevant (and in the few places where blanks are counted for, their inconsistency can cause but an inconvenience - rarely an error) ;-) And the problem of capitalization, in ones which are case sen. can easily be solved by simply not using it, therefore making the problem non existant.

Comment: @Jon - Courtesy has nothing to do with it, on the contrary. If the poster really cared *that much* about the reader, he surely would've gone to the trouble of investigating the problem himself. From the standpoint of the reader, no one is *forcing* him to trouble himself either. So without further ado, either help or don't. Rectify if you with, or don't. But don't try making your issues other people's problems.

Comment: @ldigas: I would hope that a poster *would* have investigated the problem before asking a question. You're right that no-one is forcing anyone to answer questions - but surely it's in a questioner's best interests to make their question as easy to understand as possible... which is also courteous. I really just don't see the problem with someone helping to make a question more readable. SO isn't meant to be about expressing a writing preference - it's about communicating information about programming. That is best done by observing normal writing conventions, in my view.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Of course. You're right. (have to end this discussion unfortunatelly, tommorow's a working day! ;-) Looking forward to repeating it or some alike next weekend as well ;-)

Comment: "The fact that Neil (or anyone else, for that matter) understood the meaning, is obvious." If I understand that correctly, it doesn't matter how much you intentionally mangle the message and how much extra processing it will require on the other end, as long as it saves you an entire extra keystroke? Or, to put it your way, "i wnat ur asnwerz,,buttimtoolazy && kewl 2 rite clarly n avryone undrstends my anywai lol"? That, to me, sounds suspiciously close to the infamous "SEND ME TEH CODEZ".

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want your questions/answers to be edited/sanitized, then just ensure that you ask the question or post the answer on a professional and smart way so that there's no need to edit it.

Those edits are mandatory to keep the overall quality of the site high. As the FAQ states, if you don't appreciate it, go look for another site, but you'll then live with the fact that you will get more risk to be flamed and/or receive unprofessional and/or low-quality answers.

*Little* effort, *major* benefit.

Answer (score 13):

As cited from the FAQ:

> Other people can edit my stuff?!
>
> Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your posts being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Comment: thanks, i hadn't know that it could be edited if i had not selected 'community wiki'. i guess i really "may not be the site for me" if this is the case.

Answer (score 10):

I've seen people get upset over removing "Hello" and "Thanks!" from posts, but I think this is the first case of someone objecting to fixing legitimate errors. Most of my edits on SO are either formatting code correctly or fixing spelling/grammar/capitalization problems. I guess if you included "by the way, please don't fix the errors in this question" I might leave it alone, but I would be slightly annoyed that you're willingly posting a lower-quality question and actively asking people not to improve it when it does no harm to you